# icefaces mobile TabSetMetaHandler(in icefaces-mobi) class not able to access class MethodRule(in icefaces)

Tags: java, tomcat, mobile, icefaces

I m developing a mobile website using icefaces-mobi framework. We have a website already developed in icefaces framework now we want to mobilise our site. After successful authentication I m returning a test view name as string (mDashboard), get resolved and tries to render mDashboard.xhtml, here is my code

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
             xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
             xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
             xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
             xmlns:mobi="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/mobile/component">
<h:head>
    <mobi:deviceResource />
</h:head>
<h:body>
<ui:composition>
        <mobi:tabSet currentId="1">

            <mobi:contentPane title="Ice Sailer" id="tab1"
                              facelet="false" client="true" >
                <h:outputText value="A" />
            </mobi:contentPane>

            <mobi:contentPane title="Ice Breaker" id="tab2"
                          facelet="false" client="true" >

                 <h:outputText value="B" />

            </mobi:contentPane>

            <mobi:contentPane title="Ice Skater" id="tab3"
                              facelet="false" client="true" >
                 <h:outputText value="C" />
            </mobi:contentPane>

        </mobi:tabSet>

</ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

But server returns http status 500 with error description

**root cause**

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: org/icefaces/facelets/tag/icefaces/core/MethodRule
    org.icefaces.mobi.component.tabset.TabSetMetaHandler.createMetaRuleset(TabSetMetaHandler.java:22)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:127)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:102)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.doNewComponentActions(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:409)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:159)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:166)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:774)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)

Please help me out.Any help will be appreciated.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is the xhtml above a fragment that's included in another page? If not, then you should remove the  as that will cut off all components outside of it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Above xhtml(mDashboard.xhtml) is not included inside any other page. I also tried the same by removing html,head,body tags.But issue is still same. :( It's a simple view name return by a backing bean's method (i.e. login method after a successful authentication). On click of login :- <mobi:commandButton value="Login" styleClass="submit" action="#{loginUIBean.login}"/> I m calling a method of bean to authenticate and it simply returns mDashboard.

Comment: Could you please list the other jars and their version included in your project? It may be a jar incompatibility. ICEmobile ships with particular versions of ICEfaces and may have issues with earlier versions. ICEmobile 1.2 shipped with ICEfaces 3.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I am using following jars:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>icefaces-compat</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>icefaces-mobi</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>icefaces-ace</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>icefaces</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But now I am facing new error:-

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: failed to append element[tag: div; attributes: ] into #document
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)

root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to append element[tag: div; attributes: ] into #document
    org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMResponseWriter.appendToCursor(DOMResponseWriter.java:431)
    org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMResponseWriter.startElement(DOMResponseWriter.java:263)
    org.icefaces.mobi.component.tabset.TabSetRenderer.encodeBegin(TabSetRenderer.java:83)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1755)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)

root cause

org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted. 
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.insertBefore(CoreDocumentImpl.java:391)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(NodeImpl.java:235)
    org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMResponseWriter.appendToCursor(DOMResponseWriter.java:426)
    org.icefaces.impl.context.DOMResponseWriter.startElement(DOMResponseWriter.java:263)
    org.icefaces.mobi.component.tabset.TabSetRenderer.encodeBegin(TabSetRenderer.java:83)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1755)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
```

**My applications flow is as follows:-**

1)This is index page-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:mobi="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/mobile/component">
<h:head>
    <title>title</title>
    <mobi:deviceResource />
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <mobi:smallView>
        <ui:param name="viewSize" value="small" />
        <ui:include src="fragments/mLoginPage.xhtml" />
    </mobi:smallView>
    <mobi:largeView>
        <ui:param name="viewSize" value="large" />
        <ui:include src="homepage.xhtml" />
    </mobi:largeView>

</h:body>
</html>
```

2)Then it renders mLoginPage.xhtml when request from android phone:-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
    xmlns:mobi="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/mobile/component" > 

    <div id="login" class="container">

        <div class="subHeader">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:panelGroup>Credentials</h:panelGroup>
            </f:facet>
        </div>

        <div class="subContent">
            <h:form id="loginForm" binding="#{loginUIBean.loginComponent}">
            <h:message for="loginForm" layout="table" class="error"/>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <mobi:fieldsetGroup>
                    <mobi:fieldsetRow>
                        <h:graphicImage value="images/MP-logo.png" style="float:center;"/>                  
                    </mobi:fieldsetRow>
                    <mobi:fieldsetRow>
                        <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Login Id:"/>
                        <mobi:inputText id="email" autocorrect="on" singleSubmit="false" type="text" placeholder="Email Id"
                            value="#{loginUIBean.loginEmailId}"/>
                    </mobi:fieldsetRow>

                    <mobi:fieldsetRow>
                        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:"/>
                        <mobi:inputText id="password" type="password" singleSubmit="false" placeholder="Password"
                            value="#{loginUIBean.password}">
                        </mobi:inputText>
                    </mobi:fieldsetRow>
                    <mobi:fieldsetRow>
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#" immediate="true" id="saveCredentials" />
                        <h:outputLabel value="Save my credentials on this mobile phone."></h:outputLabel>
                    </mobi:fieldsetRow>
                    <mobi:fieldsetRow>
                        <mobi:commandButton value="Login" styleClass="submit" action="#{loginUIBean.login}"/>
                    </mobi:fieldsetRow>            
                </mobi:fieldsetGroup>
            </div>  
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </div>

</html>
```

3)Then it goes to login method of backing bean doing authentication successfully:-
    class LoginUiBean

```
public String login(){
   //logic to auth.
   //----
    return "mDashboard";

}
```

4)Then sample mDashboard(or any page which contains ice-mobi components page) I m expecting to see on screen:-

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
             xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
             xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
             xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
             xmlns:mobi="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/mobile/component">

    <mobi:tabSet currentId="1">

            <mobi:contentPane title="Ice Sailer" id="tab1"
                              facelet="false" client="true" >
                <h:outputText value="A" />
            </mobi:contentPane>

            <mobi:contentPane title="Ice Breaker" id="tab2"
                          facelet="false" client="true" >

                 <h:outputText value="B" />

            </mobi:contentPane>

            <mobi:contentPane title="Ice Skater" id="tab3"
                              facelet="false" client="true" >
                 <h:outputText value="C" />
            </mobi:contentPane>

        </mobi:tabSet>

</ui:composition>
```

But it throws above error trace.

Answer (score 0):

Since mLoginPage.xhtml is a fragment you should use a ui:composition tag instead of the  tag, or just add a ui:composition tag directly following the .

Comment: as said I removed html tag from mLoginPage.xhtml and used ui:composition tag, but as per my understanding I am rendering fresh view (mDashboard.xhtml) as it has nothing to do with previous views in the browser. when I am using ui composition tag in mDashboard it throws an error- javax.servlet.ServletException: failed to append element[tag: div; attributes: ] into #document javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)root cause
java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to append element[tag: div; attributes: ] into #document But if I removed ui:composition it renders unexpected view